# Why can't I download any files from BOX with cURL

Tags: curl, box-api

When I run the command below, it returns all of the expected data and information about the file. I am the owner of the file and can download it directly from the Box website

`curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/1790744170/ -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"`

But this command (below),

`curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/1790744170/data -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"`

Will return nothing, not even a HTTP error code, all curl does is sit for a second and go back to prompt. I tried `curl [etctera] > testfile` and it popped up the little status bar and at the end all of the values were zero eg:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because downloads through the Box API are actually 302'd to a temporary resource at dl.boxcloud.com. You can force cURL to follow the redirect by including the `-L` flag i.e.

```
curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content  \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
```

(the docs did not reflect this but are now updated to show the flag).

Comment: Thanks... not exactly what I was looking for but this answers the question no :P

Comment: and do you happen to know how long 'temporarily' is?